# What is the advantage of being a Math/CS double major in graduate admissions for someone who wants to work in TCS?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

Doing original research in Theoretical Computer Science requires a quite good understanding of almost all areas of Mathematics.
I think double majoring in Mathematics and Computer science for someone who wants to do research in Theory is very important.(Or at least having a knowledge of Algebra, Analysis, Logic, Topology etc.)

I'm wondering how do graduate admission offices take this as an advantage?( Specifically in comparison with other good applicants which have publications or higher GPAs.)

Thanks.

Comment: Anything that "requires a quite good understanding of almost all areas of mathematics" would require multiple lifetimes of preparation.  Unless you mean almost all areas of *undergraduate* mathematics.  But do you really need to know, say, differential equations for TCS?

Comment: I'm not aware of any applications of Differential Equations in TCS but maybe that's because there are a few people knowing both Differential Equations and let's say Complexity Theory. Of course understanding all areas of mathematics can't go further than undergrad mathematics, but in some areas we need much more than that.

Comment: Doing original research in theoretical computer science requires a good understanding of _some_ areas of mathematics; _which_ areas it requires obviously depend on what kind of theoretical computer science you want to do.  Every area of mathematics is useful for TCS (yes, even differential equations), but unless you're Terry Tao, you can't master everything.

Comment: @JeffE Definitely, But my point is that a theoretician(including PhD students) must have a knowledge of almost _all_ areas of mathematics at undergrad level(like Analysis, Algebra, Logic, Topology, Set Theory, Number Theory, Algebraic Geometry & Topology). The least advantage is that you can _talk_ to math people, see what they're doing and get ideas from them.

Comment: I understand your point, but I disagree.  It's enough to be familiar with _some_ areas of math; some TCS folks do quite well with _no_ expertise in math (except, of course, TCS itself).

Comment: To split the difference here, you need to know enough to recognize things ("Oh wait, that might be a variety"), but you don't need to know enough to apply a theorem from the top of your head ("Let's throw theorem XYZ at it") - the latter can be obtained if you have the former by reading and talking **when needed**. JeffE's point is to do lazy querying (to use a CS term :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally rate strong math skills as a major plus when it comes to looking at applicants. This is not superior to having actual research experience, but it definitely helps an application. For many areas of TCS, a strong math background can be more valuable than a strong CS background that is weak on TCS.

But students with a strong math background AND a weaker TCS background tend to need a little reprogramming when it comes to asking questions :) - they are good at answering them though.

Comment: I agree.  But it really doesn't matter whether an applicant actually _majored_ in math.  I'd personally prefer an applicant who _didn't_ double major, but instead took some interesting grad-level math classes.

Comment: @JeffE Why do you prefer non-double majors?

Comment: @Kaave: It's a mild preference.  Satisfying the requirements of a second major requires jumping a lot of administrative hurdles, which potentially distract from learning interesting math and doing research.

Answer (score 5):

Studying mathematics is great, and I agree that many theoretical computer science students would benefit from studying more mathematics.  However, double majoring is definitely not a must, and it will help only slightly with admission.  It could serve as a tie-breaker, but it is less important than getting good grades and much less important than doing research.  Ultimately, a double major is worthwhile if you would enjoy it or find it useful, but the learning will have to be its own reward.

Comment: Yes, I should relax my claim a little bit but I think it's better to point it out in an extreme way :)